# Communication mechanism among windows or pages WPF

Tags: c#, .net, patterns-and-practices, wpf

I work with `C#` and `WPF` and not using `MVVM` approach.  One of the important part of applications is communication among `Windows` `Pages` and `UserControls`. In `MVVM` they do it behind the scenes and let you use some method to make it possible to send or receive data among different instances.

In code behind, Parent and child windows can communicate easily by just passing or assigning `ParentWindow` reference to `ChildWindow`.  To make communication possible among different windows or pages. But what I've done is,

Created a **Static Class** named as **Operator.cs** that has a `List<Window> AvailableWindows`  . Now every time we create a window, we push this instance into `List<Windows> AvailableWindows`  and when closing window remove that instance from `AvailableWindows` . This way I've reference to available pages or windows and from anywhere i can access it and do whatever and can communicate among many instances easily.

```
public static class Operator
{
    public Operator()
    {
    }
    public static List<Page> AvailablePages = new List<Page>();
    public static List<Window> AvailableWindows = new List<Window>();

}
```

**My question is, if it's a good approach, bad or just Ok ? or any other alternative ?**

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what it is you are trying to accomplish by having the pages being able to reference each other. I would tend to be concerned about a separation of concerns with pages eventually being spaghetti coded together, with page A reaching over into window B which reaches over to page C which reaches back to page A, etc.

If the use cases are event-like, I would probably use the mediator pattern (https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/mediator) to allow the individual pages to pub-sub to events. While this pattern is often used in MVVM as well, it doesn't rely on MVVM. You also seem similar ideas in JavaScript webapps, so it isn't technology-specific.

Comment: What i'm doing is also something like `Mediator` like pattern. isn't it ? the `Operator` class acting like an mediator and helping me communicate with other instances. And that's what i'm doing here (communication e.g doing somthing on one window that should reflect some results on other window).

Comment: It's similar, the advantage to the mediator is that by avoiding direct pointer access between windows, you can be far more precise about what information is needed and keep it to a minimum. My guess would be that the operator class would work fine on day one and eventually get spaghetti like, but either will work with sufficient discipline.